# Using Ninject and Ninject.Extensions.Conventions with referenced assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm trying to get `Ninject` set up with an `ASP.NET MVC 4` project.

I have 3 projects in my solution. The main MVC 4 web app, that has references to 2 supporting assemblies (`My.Services.dll` and `My.Repository.dll`). `My.Services.dll` also has a reference to `My.Repository.dll`.

I have added the Nuget packages: Ninject.MVC3 (version 3.0.0.6) and Ninject.Extensions.Conventions (version 3.0.0.11)

In the main web application I have a `Home controller` with the following constructor

```
public HomeController(IMyService myService)
{
    _myService = myService;
}
```

The service has a constructor like so:

```
public MyService(IMyRepository myRepository)
{
    _myRepository = myRepository;
}
```

In my NinjectWebCommon file I have:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind(x =>
            {
                x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface();
                //x.FromAssemblyContaining<MyRepository>().SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface();
                //x.FromAssemblyContaining<MyService>().SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface();
                x.From("My.Repository", "My.Services").SelectAllTypes().BindDefaultInterface();

            });
        }
```

If I run the application I get an error (`"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: first"`) on the last line of the `RegisterServices` method.

You can see in the code that I've also tried `x.FromAssemblyContaining<MyRepository>().SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface()` to no avail.

Incidentally, If I put the 2 types, `MyService` and `MyRepository` in the web application and not in the satellite assemblies and remove the last line of  RegisterServices then all dependencies are resolved and everything works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have **one `From...` expression inside in a `kernel.Bind` call**.

So call your `FromAssemblyContaining` in different `kernel.Bind` 
statements, and it should work fine:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                  .SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface());
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssemblyContaining<MyRepository>()
                  .SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface());
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssemblyContaining<MyService>()
                  .SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface());
```

Comment: Thank you, I would never have thought of that.

Comment: Me neither, for me it was also not obvious what is the problem. There isn't any complex example on the github site of the extension... I had to look up the source to check what goes wrong.